# content in tableview cell overlapping

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios6

I created a prototype cell in  storyboard with  four labels

then in my code i am adding different background images for first,last and other rows.
for first row all 4 labels are hidden.

Intially all 5 rows shown in screen appear good.but when i scroll up to see 6th row ,it behaves like first row and all 4 labels are hidden.

here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{

Employee *currentEmployee=[Employee sharedData];
NSArray *tempArray =currentEmployee.leaveApproveDict;
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"approveLeaveCell";


approveLeaveCell *cell = [self.approveLeaveView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[approveLeaveCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}


if([tempArray count]!=0){
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"h_t_top_bar.png"]];
        cell.backgroundView = imgView;
        cell.fromLabel.hidden=YES;
        cell.toLabel.hidden=YES;
        cell.typeLabel.hidden=YES;
        cell.nameLabel.hidden=YES;
        [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
    else{
        if(indexPath.row ==[tempArray count]){
            UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"h_t_bottom_bar.png"]];
            cell.backgroundView = imgView;
        }
        else{
            UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"h_t_repeat_bar.png"]];
            cell.backgroundView = imgView;

        }

        //assign the data
        if(indexPath.row-1 < [tempArray count]){
            NSDictionary *tempLeave= [currentEmployee.leaveApproveDict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
            cell.toDateLabel.text=[self extractLeaveDate:(NSString*) [tempLeave objectForKey:@"leaveTo"]];
            cell.fromDateLabel.text=[self extractLeaveDate:(NSString*)[tempLeave objectForKey:@"leaveFrom"]];
            cell.leaveLabel.text=[tempLeave objectForKey:@"leaveType"];
            cell.employeeNameLabel.text=[tempLeave objectForKey:@"requesterName"];

    }
}

return cell;
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same issue happens with me. I have solved it using two different customized `UITableViewCell` and two identifiers.

A `UITableView` object maintains a queue (or list) of the currently reusable cells, each with its own reuse identifier, and makes them available to the delegate in the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`: method.

Comment: i tried even before to create two different customised cells,but didn't work,.........after your suggestion i tried again,but now i added another return statement when row is zero......it solved my problem....thanks for your inputs..

Comment: now i am adding check mark when i tap on my table view cell,but check mark is repeated in other cells when i scroll

Comment: Thumbrule for multiple types of rows in uitableviewcell is you use different custom cell with different identifier. Repetation will not happen then. Use Check mark as an image view in custom cell

Comment: i fixed it,i am adding indexpath of selected cells into array,then in cellForRowAtIndex:  i am showing checkmark if indexpath is in array.

Comment: For multiple row selection array is ok, but if you want for single selection then take int or bool.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use ARC in your project? If you did not use arc, then cell should use autorelease:

```
cell = [[[approveLeaveCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 /* Remove all existing content from list and reload them again to avoid 
     * overlay of cell content */

    for(UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews){
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
// VKJ
```

Comment: `[view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]` seems redundant?